# MIPS Assembly program to calculate the trace of a matrix after taking an integer input

Tags: assembly, matrix, mips, trace

The following is my MIPS assembly code which refuses to work for some reason. SOMEONE please rescue me, i've been stuck for 3 weeks!!! I'm supposed to read in an int n, square it, then read in the the n(squared) values into a matrix then calculate the trace of the matrix. I read onto and off a stack, but somewhere along the lines, i must have a simple logic error which i cant identify. Thanks in advance:

```
.data                           #string variable declarations
get_int: .asciiz   "Please enter an int value n: "  #prompts user to enter a number
newline: .asciiz   "\n" 
.text 

.globl main 

main:   

addi $sp, $sp, -12                      #create a stack (stack frame..)
sw   $ra, 0($sp)                        #storage for stack elements
sw   $s0, 4($sp)      
sw   $s1, 8($sp)      
sw   $s2, 12($sp)               

li $v0, 5                       #Read input 
syscall
move $s0, $v0                       #$s0 = $v0 

mult $s0 $s0                            #square the entered int
mflo $t2
li $t0, $t2       #t0 receives the squared value from $t2


#adding stuff to the stack

li $t1, 0                       #t1 is our counter (i) 

stackloop:
beq $t1, $t0, endstackloop                  #exit loop when t1== $t0


li $v0, 5                       #Read input 
syscall
move $t5, $v0                       #$t5 = $v0 

addi $sp, $sp, -4
sw $t5, 0($sp)

addi $t1, $t1, 1                    #add 1 to t1
j stackloop                         #jump back to the top of loop

stackpop:

lw $t3, 0($sp)      #t3 = 1st value from stack 
add $s1, $s1, $t3   #adding that 1st value to sum
addi $sp, $sp, 4    #moving to the next stack element
sub $t1, $t1, 1     #decrementing counter by 1
add $t4, $t4, $0    #setting comparison value to 0

matrixcondition:
beq $t1, $0, output
lw $t3, 0($sp)
sub $t1, $t1, 1         #decrementing counter by 1
beq $s0, $t4, matrixtrace   #jump to matrixtrace when equal 
add $t4, $t4, 1         #add 1 to t4
j matrixcondition

matrixtrace:
add $s1, $s1, $t3   #adding that next value to sum
add $t4, $0, $0     #setting comparison value to 0
j matrixcondition

output:
li $v0, 4
syscall
j progterminate

progterminate:

lw $ra, 0($sp)                      #restoring the stack pointer

addi $sp, $sp, 8

jr $ra                          #return
```

Comment: You haven't stated what the problem is. What's the expected behaviour, and what's the actual behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

These are the errors I found:

1. This

   ```
   li $t0, $t2       #t0 receives the squared value from $t2
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   move $t0, $t2       #t0 receives the squared value from $t2
   ```
2. `endstackloop` does not exists.
3. This

   ```
   add $t4, $t4, $0    #setting comparison value to 0
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   li $t4, 0    #setting comparison value to 0
   ```

If you provide more information on what is not working, we can help better.